# Inline text with 2 column div

Tags: css, html

I use div to replace table for 2 column. I have problem to display them in good view if 1st column text too long. For example: 'Spoken' should be inline with 'English' but not 'Loans, Dental' from previous 2nd column.

```
#wrap {
 width:280px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.left_col {
 float:left;
 width:30%;
}
.right_col {
float:right;
width:70%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HtyXP/

Comment: so you want to overflow the two elements synchronically? i mean so to say: `if left_col.overflow() then call right_col.overflow() && if right_col.overflow() then call left_col.overflow()`

Comment: It looks to me like a table would be better in this situation. Is there any particular reason that you want to use two divs?

Comment: I would like to learn div for 2 column cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i see to fix this is either a table, or if you want to stick to divs desparately this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="left_col">Industry:</div>
    <div class="right_col">Insurance</div>
  </div><div class="row">
    <div class="left_col">Co. Size:</div>
    <div class="right_col">201 - 500 Employees</div>
  </div><div class="row">
    <div class="left_col">Working Hours:</div>
    <div class="right_col">Regular hours, Mondays-Fridays</div>
  </div><div class="row">
    <div class="left_col">Benefits:</div>
    <div class="right_col">Medical, Education support, Loans, Dental</div>
  </div><div class="row">
    <div class="left_col">Spoken Language:</div>
    <div class="right_col">English</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is caused because you set the width to 280px (#wrap). `Medical, Education support, Loans, Dental` is a very long sentence and it is overflowing the 70% of the `right_col`. The same thing with the `Language spoken`.

To make everything look good, you have to increase this value. A width of 400px should work.

Comment: now we take given, that there is for whatever reason still an overflow, because the line simply got too long?? or put that into a sidebar and whoops you still got the problem.

Comment: you set the width to 280px and the sentence just passed the 70% of these 280px, making it to start a new line, consequently using the space that you actually reserved for the Language spoken

Comment: yep. and that exactly is described problem, and i am sorry to say your answer would not help.

Comment: I can't set width more than that. Is that any better option or better code?

Comment: If you want, you can try to make the font smaller... Vogel612's idea is also good

Comment: Vogel612's idea is very reliable, since when you overflow the `right_col` or `left_col`, the other `divs` will not be affected. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tsalzmann/VPx6c/

Comment: @Tiago Salzmann : That is what I want but what is css class for row? So adding clear will fix it?

Comment: you can just leave row blanc. if I put a div in another div and set `float: right` in the inner div, the outer div will have a height of 0px. In our case, we don't want that. So we "clear" the `float` after using it...

Comment: Here you can see what happens if you don't clear the `float` (notice that it is exaclty your initial problem): http://jsfiddle.net/tsalzmann/jWWsF/1/